# How to set multi currencies rates with Apex?

Tags: apex, webservices, multi-currency

My name is Pavel and I am pretty new to salesforce.
Was wondered if somebody faced with the same issue:
I would like to set multi-currencies rates with a help of Apex code daily. I will receive such JSON from servicewith rates:

```
{
    "status": "Success",
    "data": [
        {
            "type": "STANDARD",
            "currencies": [
                {
                    "currency": "AED",
                    "midRate": 0.4629,
                    "buyRate": 0.4629,
                    "sellRate": 0.4629
                },
                {
                    "currency": "AUD",
                    "midRate": 1.0076,
                    "buyRate": 1.0076,
                    "sellRate": 1.0076
                },
                {
                    "currency": "CAD",
                    "midRate": 1.1941,
                    "buyRate": 1.1941,
                    "sellRate": 1.1941
                },
                {
                    "currency": "CHF",
                    "midRate": 1.7448,
                    "buyRate": 1.7448,
                    "sellRate": 1.7448
                },
                {
                    "currency": "CNY",
                    "midRate": 0.2391,
                    "buyRate": 0.2391,
                    "sellRate": 0.2391
                },
                {
                    "currency": "DKK",
                    "midRate": 0.2483,
                    "buyRate": 0.2483,
                    "sellRate": 0.2483
                },
                {
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "midRate": 1.855,
                    "buyRate": 1.855,
                    "sellRate": 1.855
                },
                {
                    "currency": "GBP",
                    "midRate": 2.0154,
                    "buyRate": 2.0154,
                    "sellRate": 2.0154
                },
                {
                    "currency": "GEL",
                    "midRate": 0.4845,
                    "buyRate": 0.4845,
                    "sellRate": 0.4845
                },
                {
                    "currency": "JPY",
                    "midRate": 0.0153,
                    "buyRate": 0.0153,
                    "sellRate": 0.0153
                },
                {
                    "currency": "KZT",
                    "midRate": 0.0038,
                    "buyRate": 0.0038,
                    "sellRate": 0.0038
                },
                {
                    "currency": "NOK",
                    "midRate": 0.1586,
                    "buyRate": 0.1586,
                    "sellRate": 0.1586
                },
                {
                    "currency": "RUB",
                    "midRate": 0.0217,
                    "buyRate": 0.0217,
                    "sellRate": 0.0217
                },
                {
                    "currency": "SEK",
                    "midRate": 0.1682,
                    "buyRate": 0.1682,
                    "sellRate": 0.1682
                },
                {
                    "currency": "TRY",
                    "midRate": 0.2636,
                    "buyRate": 0.2636,
                    "sellRate": 0.2636
                },
                {
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "midRate": 1.7,
                    "buyRate": 1.7,
                    "sellRate": 1.7
                },
                {
                    "currency": "XAU",
                    "midRate": 2202.9811,
                    "buyRate": 2202.9811,
                    "sellRate": 2202.9811
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And I would like to change rates in my org according to them.
I will be really glad for any help.
Much appreciated, Pavel

Comment: You can use the [DatedConversionRate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_datedconversionrate.htm) object to store this data. This will allow certain fields to be automatically converted to a user's display currency based on a specific field. If you have specific questions or are somehow stuck, please provide specific questions we can answer. You can read more about our expectations in [ask] and take the [tour] to see some good questions.

Comment: SFDC only supports one rate per currency per timeperiod. You have three rates: mid, buy, sell. This is going to require a custom object

Answer (score 0):

you can update the currency rate with an API Call. You can try the below sample in your Developer Console. Insert the ID of currency type to the currency Id of your org. One call per currency. This way you can do it with a scheduled Apex class on a daily base.

```
Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/CurrencyType/<Id>?_HttpMethod=PATCH');
    req.setBody('{ "ConversionRate" : 1.1152 }');
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot
Best regards, Pavel